# How to generate a list of links for each X number of prior months?

Tags: php, html

I'm attempting to generate a list of links, one for each month starting at the current month and working backwards for X number of months.

I have something mostly working, with the exception that it is "skipping" the month of February 2013. Here is a screenshot of what I have now:

[image]

Here is the code from the view template that is generating that list:

```
        <?php for( $i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++ ): ?>
            <li>
                <?php $prior_time = strtotime( "-$i month" ); ?>
                <?php $month = date( 'm', $prior_time ); ?>
                <?php $year = date( 'Y', $prior_time ); ?>
                <?php $day = date( 't', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year ) ); ?>
                <?php $prior_month_string = date( 'F', $prior_time ); ?>
                <?php $prior_month_from = date( 'm/01/Y', $prior_time ); ?>
                <?php $prior_month_to = date( "m/$day/Y", $prior_time ); ?>
                <?php if( date( 'F', strtotime( $selected_from ) ) == $prior_month_string ): ?>
                    <?php echo $prior_month_string; ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <a href='/claims?<?php echo "from=$prior_month_from&to=$prior_month_to"; ?>'
                       data-from='<?php echo $prior_month_from; ?>'
                       data-to='<?php echo $prior_month_to; ?>'>
                        <?php echo $prior_month_string; ?>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endfor; ?>
```

The funny thing is, if I extend the `for` loop to run up through `$i <= 18`, it *does* display February 2012. But for some reason, when attempting to display February 2013, it instead displays another March 2013 (example of issue shown in above screenshot).

It seems like the issue is here:

```
$prior_time = strtotime( "-$i month" );
```

But, I am at a loss as to *why* and how to get around it.  Why does this algorithm spit out a second March 2013 instead of February 2013 and how can I get around this oddity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today is the 29th, and there is no February 29, 2013; that equates to March 1, 2013.

To get around it, I would generate your dates based on the 1st of the month (instead of calculating based on today's date).

Comment: Good thing today was the 29th and it wasn't a leap year. A future problem avoided.

Comment: Thanks, good eyes!  I implemented your solution like this: `strtotime( "-$i month", strtotime( date( 'm/01/y' ) ) );`